# Desktop SPARQL client for Jena (TDB)?

Tags: client, rdf, sparql, jena

I'm working on an app that uses Jena for storage (with the TDB backend). I'm looking for something like the equivalent of Squirrel, that lets me see what's being stored, run queries etc. This seems like an obvious thing to need, but my (perhaps badly phrased) google queries aren't turning up anything promising.

Any suggestions, please? I'm on XP. Even a command line tool would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at my [Store Manager](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=Store%20Manager) tool which is part of the [dotNetRDF Toolkit](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=Tools) which I develop as part of the wider [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) project I maintain.

It provides a fairly basic GUI through which you can connect to various Triple Stores including TDB provided that you expose your dataset via Joseki/Fuseki.  You need to have .Net 3.5 installed to run the apps in the toolkit.

If you don't already expose your TDB dataset via HTTP try using Fuseki as it is ridiculously easy to use and can be run just on your local machine when necessary to make your TDB store available via HTTP for use with my tool e.g.

```
java -jar fuseki-0.1.0-server.jar --update --loc data /dataset
```

Please see the [Fuseki wiki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/) for more information on running Fuseki and the various options.  In the above example Fuseki is run with SPARQL Update enabled (the --update flag), using the TDB dataset located in the directory **data** (the --loc data argument) and with a base URI of **/dataset** for the data.

Once running you can use my tool to connect to a Fuseki server by going to File > New Generic Store Manager, selecting the "Fuseki" tab from the dialog that appears, entering  the URI http://localhost:3030/dataset/data and then clicking "Connect to Fuseki".

Comment: Thanks - that was pretty easy to follow. However, nothing is showing up under Graphs. I'm a bit troubled by the fact that Fuseki produces identical output when I point it at either a real TDB director, or a nonsense one (in the latter case, it seems to create a new db there). Maybe there's something odd about the contents of my tdb, like it doesn't have named graphs or something. I just don't know about this stuff to be able to debug it meaningfully.

Comment: TDB always creates a new store if you point it to a directory where no TDB store exists, for testing purposes you can replace `--loc data` with `--mem` which creates a temporary in-memory store instead.  It is possible to have a TDB store without named graphs if I remember rightly.  Depending on how you import data into the store it will not necessarily get imported into a named graph so nothing would show up in the graph list.  The import tool within my app should import things as named graphs, I think the fuseki web interface imports things into the default unnamed graph

Answer (score 1):

Twinkle is a handy SPARQL client : http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/

As it happens I'm working on something similar myself, but it still needs a lot of work (check back in a month :) http://hyperdata.org/wiki/Scute

Answer (score 1):

1. first download jena fusaki from

> https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi

1. un-zip the file and copy the "jena-fuseki-1.0.1" to c drive
2. open cmd
3. type  for accesing the folder

> "cd C:\jena-fuseki-1.0.1"

then type

> "java -jar fuseki-server.jar --update --loc data /dataset"

at last open a browser and type

> "localhost:3030/"

remember you must first declear the enviorment verible(located in system poperties then advance tab) 
 and edit variable name call "Path" in the "System verible" to

> "C:\jena-fuseki-1.0.1"

Comment: I am using Windows 7 (32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

I also develop a SPARQL client, Open Source in Java Swing: EulerGUI.
In fact it does a lot more, see the manual:
http://eulergui.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eulergui/trunk/eulergui/html/documentation.html

For the SPARQL feature, better take the EulerGUI minimal build:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eulergui/files/eulergui/1.11/

Comment: There is a new release 1.12 of EulerGUI, with SPARQL update GUI : dowload :  http://sourceforge.net/projects/eulergui